# How do I create a "tips" popup in vim

Tags: vim

I have a few tips I am trying to remember in VIM. What would be cool is if I could get these to open in a horizontal split at the top of the current window with a keystroke (say F4), then hide again (toggle) when hitting F4 again.

So how can I get a text file to open in a (smallish) split above my current window with a toggle keypress?

Perhaps there is a plugin I don't know about that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.  It will work in normal mode only so it doesn't interfere with actually typing an `<F4>`.  Add it to your `.vimrc`.  Loads the file specified into a preview window.  In this case it is `~/vimtips.txt`

View this link for more on the preview window. You can set things like the size of the preview window with some other options: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#preview-window

```
let g:MyVimTips="off"
function! ToggleVimTips()
  if g:MyVimTips == "on"
    let g:MyVimTips="off"
    pclose
  else
    let g:MyVimTips="on"
    pedit ~/vimtips.txt
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <F4> :call ToggleVimTips()<CR>
```

Comment: That could not be anymore perfect!

Comment: Actually it can. Test the buffer is opened in a preview windows instead of using a global-and-visible variable. The test becomes: `if getwinvar(bufwinnr('~/vimtips.txt'), '&previewwindow')`. We can also make `ToggleVimTips` script local (for pollution aspects), or move it into an autoload plugin to improve vim startup.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the accepted answer (which is a good one!) is to make a plugin that just contains a 'doc' (help page) part. I have done this for years to keep my own list of notes and tips. I call my plugin 'ooo' so ':help ooo' brings up the help page. Whether this is 'better' or 'worse' than the accepted answer is up to the individual

Comment: Nice idea. Your answer could be improved with a ready-to-use example. You might want to show a directory tree and installation instructions (e.g. you will need to run `:helptags` unless you use a plugin manager that does that for you).